# Is there documentation for Android Skia logcat output?

Tags: android, documentation, skia

I'm sometimes getting this message in logcat:

```
11-09 14:24:04.680: D/skia(2111): --- gOptions_mCancelID
```

and I don't know what it means.  Googling it found a C++ file which, presumably, represents an instantiation of the bitmap factory:

[BitmapFactory.cpp](http://www.myhieron.com/public/android/base/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp)

Reading through the C++ file would be fun and all, but is there some documentation on what these messages might mean?  There have been several times when I've had to track down weird bugs and the Skia messages later proved relevant, or at least looked like they might have been relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log line of `D/skia(2111): --- gOptions_mCancelID` means that a cancel of an image decode has occurred. This happens when you calling [`BitmapFactory.Options.html#requestCancelDecode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#requestCancelDecode()) in your code.

Just some notes on using this method, 
- On Android N and higher this method is deprecated and does not do anything other than set the `mCancel` field of your `BitmapFactory.Options` object to `true`
- On M and below, it will cancel the decode. If you do this you should create a new `BitmapFactory.Options` object.

More info :

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#requestCancelDecode()
- source for `requestCancelDecode()`

  - [on android M and earlier](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L369)
  - [on android N](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/nougat-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L381)

Comment: I asked this question WAYYY before N but this is fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With an Android device connected via USB, sending
`adb logcat skia:D *:S`
via command line will set any messages with 'skia' in them to **show** if they carry priority 'D' or above.  Finding what keywords other than 'skia' to be relevant would be your bag; the documentation for Logcat leaves the command not well-explained.  I am working on a visual alternative, which I'll post on my site (wikipeeria).

Comment: I think the Skia messages are just using the equivalent of `Log.d("TAG", "Message")` so they wouldn't be mentioned in the logcat documentation (any more than my logcat messages are!) but this is a pretty useful idea, thanks.  I tend to get hundreds of just this message at a time, though, so I am still going to be fishing for a while ....

Answer (score 1):

Yes,there is little doc about SKIA. You can get some information from Skia's main page from http://code.google.com/p/skia/ . And, you can search the bug's about skia in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list with the key word. The most work i think is reading the code and debugging the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation and more info here: https://skia.org/